# function vs property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, function, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Method, Property and Function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246883/what-is-method-property-and-function)

Can anyone tell me what is *function* and what is *property*?
Just a basic explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property denotes the object's state, Method denotes the object's behavior. Function is like method except for that it's not dependent upon an object (I'm guessing you don't really mean that).
For example, if you have a Car class, a property may be it's model, it's year, it's current speed etc., a method may be Stop, Drive etc.

Answer (score 1):

see msdn: [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, pragmatically, properties will 'interact' with some tools.  For instance, they will show up in the Properties window of VS.